# Delphi query custom attribute from interface

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have declared the following custom attribute

```
unit SpecialAttribute;

interface

type
  TSpecialAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
  procedure SetValue(aValue: String);
  public
    FValue: String;
    property Value: String read FValue write SetValue;
    constructor Create(const AValue: String);
  end;

implementation

{ TSpecialAttribute }

constructor TSpecialAttribute.Create(const AValue: String);
begin
  FValue := aValue;
end;

procedure TSpecialAttribute.SetValue(aValue: String);
begin
  FValue := aValue;
end;

end.
```

and used to decorate the following interface:

```
unit ITestInterface;

interface

uses
  SpecialAttribute;

type
  ITestIntf = interface(IInvokable)
    [TSpecialAttribute('IntfAttribute')]
    procedure Test;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

And I'm trying to get the attribute from the interface using RTTI:

```
unit Unit17;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
    SpecialAttribute,ITestInterface;

  type
    TTestClass = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestIntf)
    [TSpecialAttribute('TestClass')]
       procedure Test;
    end;

  TForm17 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form17: TForm17;

implementation

uses
  Rtti;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm17.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LType: TRttiType;
  LAttr: TCustomAttribute;
begin    
  try
  LContext := TRttiContext.Create;

  LType := LContext.GetType(TypeInfo(ITestIntf)); 

  for LAttr in LType.GetAttributes() do
    if LAttr is TSpecialAttribute then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(TSpecialAttribute(LAttr).FValue)
    else
     Memo1.Lines.Add(LAttr.ClassName);
  finally
    LContext.Free;
  end;
end;


end.
```

When setting breakpoints on the custom attribute constructor, the code never stops. How can I get the attributes from the interface?

Comment: You are applying the attributes to **methods** of the interface and implementing class, not to the interface/class themselves, but you are querying for attributes of the interface itself.  So, of course nothing will appear in your Memo, because you are querying for attributes at the wrong level.  You need to first enumerate the interface/object's methods using `TRttiType.Get(Declared)Methods()`, and then you can query each method's attributes using `TRttiMethod.GetAttributes()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Remy Lebeau's comment I've managed to solve it. Having the following declaration of interface:

```
unit ITestInterface;

interface

uses
  SpecialAttribute;

type
 [TSpecialAttribute('IntfAttribute - class')]
  ITestIntf = interface(IInvokable)
  [TSpecialAttribute('IntfAttribute - method')]
    procedure Test([TSpecialAttribute('IntfAttribute - params')]i: Integer);
  end;

implementation

end.
```

1) get the attribute for decorated methods:

```
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LType: TRttiType;
  LAttr: TCustomAttribute;
  lMethod: TRttiMethod;
begin
  try
    LContext := TRttiContext.Create;

    LType := LContext.GetType(TypeInfo(ITestIntf));

    for lMethod in LType.GetMethods do
    begin
      for LAttr in lMethod.GetAttributes do
      if LAttr.ClassType = TSpecialAttribute then
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(LAttr.ClassName + ' value ' + TSpecialAttribute(LAttr).Value);
      end
      else
        Memo1.Lines.Add(LAttr.ClassName);
    end;
  finally
    LContext.Free;
  end;
```

returns - *TSpecialAttribute value IntfAttribute - method*

2) get the atttributes for decorated parameters:

```
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LType: TRttiType;
  lMethod: TRttiMethod;
  lParam: TRttiParameter;
  lAttr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  try
  LContext := TRttiContext.Create;

  LType := LContext.GetType(TypeInfo(ITestIntf));
   for lMethod in LType.GetMethods do
   begin
     for lParam in lMethod.GetParameters do
      for lAttr in lParam.GetAttributes do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Attribute ' + lAttr.ClassName + ' found on parameter '+ lParam.Name);
        if lAttr.ClassType = TSpecialAttribute then
          Memo1.Lines.Add( '  value ' + TSpecialAttribute(lAttr).Value);
      end;
   end;
  finally
    LContext.Free;
  end;
end;
```

returns *Attribute TSpecialAttribute found on parameter i
  value IntfAttribute - params*

3) get the attribute which decorates the class

```
 var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LType: TRttiType;
  LAttr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  try
  LContext := TRttiContext.Create;

  LType := LContext.GetType(TypeInfo(ITestIntf));

  for LAttr in LType.GetAttributes() do
    if LAttr is TSpecialAttribute then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(TSpecialAttribute(LAttr).FValue)
    else
     Memo1.Lines.Add(LAttr.ClassName);
  finally
    LContext.Free;
  end;
end;
```

returns *IntfAttribute - class*